# Draw a small square inside listView

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I'm wonder how to draw a small square with a icon inside the `listView` like image below

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="   Description   :  " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Project"
        android:text="   Progress       :  " />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Project"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="   Project  " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Percentage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/line"
            android:text="TimeIn" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/out"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/out"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TimeOut" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> How can I draw a small square and add below Project (id is project) ?

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create a `Shape drawable` for that rounded corner square in your `drawable` folder inside `res` directory say rectangular_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

Now you just need to create a `TextView` in your `ListView` row xml and assign this `Shape drawable` to your `TextView`. Also you can specify `drawableRight` for your `TextView` to show that icon on the right of text.

```
      <TextView 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/rectangular_shape"
          android:drawablePadding="8dp"
          android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_your_icon"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:text="dummy text"/>
```

Hope this will work for you..!!